# My windows 10 doesn't display icons properly

Tags: windows-10, icons, emoji

For example, when I press right-click on the desktop you can see a rectangle instead of indicators see the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. Run in order below:

(a) dism.exe /online /cleanup-image  /restorehealth

(b) SFC /SCANNOW

Rest and test. This will likely fix the issue.

If this does not correct the issue, run a Windows 10 Repair Install:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Run.
This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Once this has finished, icons should be normal.

Once the above has all been completed, if the issue is still there, back up the system (all the data) and reinstall Windows.

Comment: none have fixed the problem

Comment: I added a final step (back up and reinstall Windows) to my answer